# Bigger cookie-like files for local data storage (browser "caching" of complex structures)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, browser, cookies, browser-cache

I am developing a browser based game, and I have a big map there. The terrain of the map is static. Therefore, I have some thousands of tiles that will not change (whether they represent a forest, a desert, whatever), just the players above it can change.

Hence, I wanted to store all my map in the player's computer. I am working with Ruby on Rails, and those map information are passed from the server to the javascript that runs on the user browser, in order to render a pretty map. But it makes me pretty sad to have a 200kb .html file, containing all those map related information.

What would be the simplest way to solve this issue? Cookies! Well. That's what I thought. A complete map information can get to almost 200kb (they are pretty big). A cookie can have at most 4kb.. I don't feel that the right way to achieve my objective is to create tons of cookies, one for each row of the map, for instance. Is there any more elegant way to have this static information lie on the player's browser, without creating lots of cookies? A way to cache it on his browser? I mean.. I can cache a 400kb image, why can't I cache a 200kb map structure?

Thanks in advance!
Fernando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, HTML [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) gives you **5 MB** (though data is *stored* *as strings*, so the actual amount of data you can fit in the container is likely a lot less than 5 MB.

This limit is oddly fluid. For one thing, it's just a *[recommended limit](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space)*; and for another, i.e., Webkit-based browsers use UTF-16, which immediately cuts that in half (2.5 MB).

Browser support for Local Storage is good: IE, Firefox, Safari 4.0+, Chrome 4.0+, and Opera 10.5+. Both iPhone and Android are supported above versions 3.0 and 2.0. respectively.

Using Local Storage to preserve game state appears to be a proto-typical [use case](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/localstorage-halma.html).

Finally, Paul Kinlan published an excellent step-by-step [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/) on **HTML5Rocks**, which i highly recommend (though it's a little more than a year old).

Comment: Damn, thanks very much! I am pretty much rushing head first into a lot of new things, and those two little words ("local storage") cleared my path :) Just to think that I was trying to use cookies for that.. awh

Comment: no problem, Fernando--i'm pleased it helped. (I also added a link in my Q above, to an excellent tutorial on the subject.)

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing. I need to initialize a variable that is stored on the user browser, with localStorage. Do you have any hint on how to send that data to the client if and only if it is already not initialized? Because.. If the user already have those data, the browser did not need to send it. However, if the user do not have that data, the browser should have sent it.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, i have always done this by first checking to see if the store exists, e.g.,                           if (!localStorage.checkins) localStorage.checkins = JSON.stringify([]);

Comment: I managed to do it, yay! The browser checks if it has the appropriate localStorage, if it does not have it, it enter a url with the parameter "?force_load=true", then the server checks if force_load is true and, if it is, it sends all the necessary data embedded in the .html, also setting it on the client browser. Then, further requests will not have to force_load anymore. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing it in a js file? Most browser will cache linked js files, allowing you to only serve it every once in a while. It would be very simple to deploy.